# Reset radio buttons when unchecking checkbox in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, checkbox, radio-button

[image: example]

In the example above, the radio buttons below the checkbox are activated when the checkbox is checked. I'd like to reset the radio buttons (so that no radio button is filled) when unchecking this checkbox.

```html
<div class="checkbox checkbox-info">
  <input id="icb" type="checkbox" ng-model="checked">
  <label for="icb"><i class="fa fa-refresh">&nbsp;</i><b>Integratie</b></label>
</div>
<div class="radio">
  <input type="radio" name="irb" id="iarb" ng-disabled="!checked" value="!checked">
  <label for="iarb">Administrator</label>
</div>
<div class="radio">
  <input type="radio" name="irb" id="imrb" ng-disabled="!checked" value="!checked">
  <label for="imrb">Medewerker</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change radio button `value` to `ng-model`

*HTML*

```
<div class="checkbox checkbox-info">
      <input id="icb" type="checkbox" ng-model="checked" ng-click="onCheck()">
      <label for="icb"><i class="fa fa-refresh">&nbsp;</i><b>Integratie</b></label>
</div>

    <div class="radio">
      <input type="radio" name="irb" id="imrb" ng-model="radio_checked" value="1" ng-disabled="!checked" />

      <label for="iarb">Administrator</label>
    </div>
    <div class="radio"> 
    <input type="radio" name="irb" id="imrb" ng-model="radio_checked" value="2" ng-disabled="!checked" />

      <label for="imrb">Medewerker</label>
    </div>
```

*JS*

```
$scope.onCheck = function(){
    $scope.radio_checked = false;    
 }
```

---

<kbd>[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c9qvydmb/)</kbd>

Comment: Follow-up question: what do I need to add so that the first radio button is selected when the checkbox is checked?